# How to Access Remote PostgreSQL Database Server Through VPN

Tags: django, database, postgresql, centos8, heidisql

I'm currently working with my office server, when i want to connect to the server, i have to use their VPN. I have installed PostgreSQL database in their server and have succesfully migrate data to database from Django project. But, when i want to remote access from HeidiSQL, it always gives me `Connection Timed Out` Error eventhough i have already connected to their VPN.

I've tried to this code below

`/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/pg_hba.conf`

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all ::/0 md5
```

`/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/postgresql.conf`

`listen_addresses = '*'`

i have tried to refresh everytime i change files and see if i'm in the correct port but it still gives me Connection Timed Out Error

this is the full error message

```
could not connect to server: Connection Timed out (0x0000274C/10060). Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432 ?
```

**NOTES**

- OS : CentOS 8
- DB : PostgreSQL 14

Comment: Not sure about what is HeidiSQL and how it should be. Does connection works form with trivial psql running on your PC? If not, it possible to start speaking about network connectivity between your PC and the server, and firewall on the server.

Comment: i've tried `psql -U <dbuser> -h <serverip> -p 5432 <dbname>` in windows ps and has the same error message

Comment: This is a VPN/firewall issue.  Problems with postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf would lead to different messages than the one you report.